# Lucid Lynx 10.04 ISO download

Tags: 10.04, iso

Where can I find Lucid Lynx 10.04 ISO image for download? I want to try something on my present Lucid system but I don't have the ISO to reinstall if everything goes sideways.

Answer (score 2):

You can download it from the official site : http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/

Answer (score 1):

http://releases.ubuntu.com/10.04.4/

Try here from

http://releases.ubuntu.com/

It archives older versions.